# Count number of words from a string input

Tags: string, mips, counting, words

In the following code, 32 is for ASCII space character. I am facing a problem in moving inside the string:

```
.data
para: .asciiz " "
buffer: .space 250
ctr: .word 0
.text
.globl main
.ent main
main:addi $t3,$0,32
li $t8,1 
la $a0,para
li $v0,8
syscall
li $t0,0
loop:bge $t0,$a0,exit
add $t1,$a0,$t0
lb $t2,0($t1)
beq $t2,$t3,counter
addi $t0,$t0,1
j loop
counter:addi $t8,$t8,1
addi $t0,$t0,1
j loop 

exit:sw $t8,ctr
li $v0,10
syscall
.end main
```

Comment: here is my latest attempt after some corrections yet unsuccessful.                                                                                              .data
para: .asciiz " "
size: .space 250
ctr: .word 0
.text
.globl main
.ent main
main:li $t3,32
li $t8,1 
la $a0,para
li $v0,8
syscall
move $a0,$a1
li $t0,0
loop:bge $t0,$a1,exit
add $t1,$a1,$t0
lb $t2,0($a1)
beq $t2,$zero,exit
beq $t5,$t3,counter
j loop
counter: addi $t8,$t8,1
j loop 
exit: sw $t8,ctr
li $v0,10
syscall
.end main

Comment: Do **not** post your code in a comment. Put your Minimal, Verifiable, and Complete example **in the question**, along with the expected behavior and the behavior you're getting.

Comment: I could not post it in the question itself due to some error

Comment: @Sanp. What error prevented you from editing your question, exactly?

Comment: when I add program it shows red everywhere(due to spelling error) , but programs should not come under that error so I could not paste program in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer today, I was comparing the array before loading individual chars:

```
.data
msg: .asciiz"Enter\n"
buffer: .space 250
ctr: .word 0

.text
.globl main
.ent main
main:addi $t3,$0,32    #$t3 holds 'space'
li $t8,1 

la $a0,msg
li $v0,4
syscall                        #$t8, is counter register

li $v0,8                          #input of string para
syscall

li $t0,0                           # i=0

loop:                    #till str[i]!=0
add $t1,$a0,$t0

lb $t2,0($t1)                   
beq $t2,$zero,exit
beq $t2,$t3,counter         #str[i]='  ' checks and jumps to 

addi $t0,$t0,1                   #increment i if false
j loop

counter: addi $t8,$t8,1     #increment counter when word 

addi $t0,$t0,1                  
j loop

exit: sw $t8,ctr
li $v0,10
syscall
.end main
```

Comment: sir you have formatted it, thanks. I am new to stack overflow.